# How do I use hparams with estimators?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, hyperparameters

To log hparams [without using Keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/hparams/api.py#L38), I'm doing the following as suggested in the tf code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/hparams/api.py#L55):

```py
with tf.summary.create_file_writer(model_dir).as_default():
    hp_learning_rate = hp.HParam("learning_rate", hp.RealInterval(0.00001, 0.1))
    hp_distance_margin = hp.HParam("distance_margin", hp.RealInterval(0.1, 1.0))
    hparams_list = [
        hp_learning_rate,
        hp_distance_margin
    ]
    metrics_to_monitor = [
        hp.Metric("metrics_standalone/auc", group="validation"),
        hp.Metric("loss", group="train", display_name="training loss"),
    ]
    hp.hparams_config(hparams=hparams_list, metrics=metrics_to_monitor)
    hparams = {
        hp_learning_rate: params.learning_rate,
        hp_distance_margin: params.distance_margin,
    }
    hp.hparams(hparams)
```

Note that `params` is a dictionary object here that I'll pass to the estimator.

Then I train the estimator as usual,

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=params.model_dir)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, params=params, config=config)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(...)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(...)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

After training, when I launch tensorboard, I do have the hparams logged, but I do not see any metrics logged against them

[image]

I further confirmed that they show up in the `scalars` page with the same tag name for both train and validation i.e. `.` and `./eval`, but the hparams page doesn't see those logged tensors.

**How do I use hparams with estimators?**

---

I'm using

```
tensorboard              2.1.0
tensorflow               2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator     2.1.0
tensorflow-metadata      0.15.2
```

on `Python 3.7.5`

---

*Attempt 1:*

After some googling, I saw some older tf code where they passed `hparams` to `params` argument of Estimator, so just to make sure if tf2 logs those hparams by itself when given, I checked the [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) docs and it says:

> The `params` argument contains hyperparameters. It is passed to the
>   `model_fn`, if the `model_fn` has a parameter named "params", and to the
>   input functions in the same manner. `Estimator` only passes params
>   along, it does not inspect it. The structure of `params` is therefore
>   entirely up to the developer.

So using hparams as params will not be useful.

---

*Attempt 2:*

I doubt that since estimators use `tensorflow.python.summary`  instead of `tf.summary` which is the default in v2, tensors logged by v1 was probably not accessible and so, I also tried to use

```
with tensorflow.python.summary.FileWriter(model_dir).as_default()
```

However that failed with `RuntimeError: tf.summary.FileWriter is not compatible with eager execution. Use tf.contrib.summary instead`.

*Update*: I ran it with eager execution disabled. Now, even the hparam initial logging did not happen. There was no `hparams` tab in tensorboard as it failed with error

```
E0129 13:03:07.656290 21584 hparams_plugin.py:104] HParams error: Can't find an HParams-plugin experiment data in the log directory. Note that it takes some time to scan the log directory; if you just started Tensorboard it could be that we haven't finished scanning it yet. Consider trying again in a few seconds.
```

Is there a way to make tensorboard read already logged metric tensors and link them with hparams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit seems to be

```
# This doesn't seem to compatible with Estimator API
hp.hparams_config(hparams=hparams_list, metrics=metrics_to_monitor)
```

Simply calling hparams logs all metrics logged with `tf.summary`. Then in tensorboard, you can filter only the metrics you need and then compare trials.

```
with tf.summary.create_file_writer(train_folder).as_default():
    # params is a dict which contains
    # { 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'distance_margin': 0.5,...}
    hp.hparams(hparams=params))
```

Comment: Hello. How do you use intervals in the `hparams`? For instance, you were trying to use `hp_learning_rate = hp.HParam("learning_rate", hp.RealInterval(0.00001, 0.1))` in the original question but ended up using `# { 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'distance_margin': 0.5,...}` in your comment. How do you specify intervals to find the best value?